# Como filtrar tweets (status) com tweepy (Cursor)

Tags: python, json, twitter-api, cursor

Peguei do livro "Mastering social media mining with python" o código abaixo, que salva todos os tweets de um usuário no formato JSON. Porém eu gostaria que salvasse em json apenas tweets de determinada data. Como fazer?

Esse é o código que salva todos os tweets:

```
fname2=dirname
fname2+= "/user_timeline.jsonl"

with open(fname2, 'w') as f:
    for page in Cursor(client.user_timeline, screen_name=screen_name, count=200).pages(16):
        for status in page:
            f.write(json.dumps(status._json)+"\n")
```

Essa é a estrutura do JSON:
https://gist.github.com/dev-techmoe/ef676cdd03ac47ac503e856282077bf2

Como posso fazer esse filtro? Outro detalhe é que no JSON vem um tweet atrás do outro entre {} mas não existe chave para ele (sem "Tweet": {.....})

Obrigada!

Comment: O que sabe de Python? Sabe o que exatamente o código que postou está fazendo? Já tentou alguma coisa?

Answer (score 1):

este código converte a string numa data:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

date = parse(date)
```